# Return the current index of element in element inside of class in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, indexing, html5-audio

I have some HTML elements like:

```
       <article class='rock' id='audioApp'>

            <section class="containerAudioApp rock">
                <audio src="audio/one.mp3"></audio>
                <audio src="audio/two.mp3"></audio>
                <button>Normal</button>
                <button>Master</button>
            </section>

            <section class="containerAudioApp rock">
                <audio src="audio/one.mp3"></audio>
                <audio src="audio/two.mp3"></audio>
                <button>Normal</button>
                <button>Master</button>
            </section>

        </article>
```

Each containerAudioApp section tag has 2 buttons and two audio tags.

What I am trying to do is:

when button **0** is clicked, audio **0** is played

when button **1** is clicked, audio **1** is played

when button **2** is clicked, audio **2** is played

and so on.

What I've done until now, is add the event listener to all buttons like this:

```
var audioApp = document.getElementById('audioApp');
var buttons = audioApp.getElementsByTagName('button');
var players = audioApp.getElementsByTagName('audio');

for(var i=0;i<buttons.length;i++){
        buttons[i].addEventListener('click', play, false);
}
```

Then the play function:

```
function play(){
    players.item(this.index).play();
}
```

I have problems with the "this.index" part, I am not sure what's the current syntax to ask JavaScript the index of the clicked item.

Any ideas?

Comment: function play(index){players[index].play();}

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Proxytype. How can I pass index variable to play function? That's my main question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve

- click button0 -> play audio0
- click button1 -> play audio1
- ...

you have to make a **dependency** between `<button>` and `<audio>`:

```
<button>Click<audio></audio></button>
```

Now every `<audio>` is the **child** of the `<button>`!

That's important for JavaScript use (**children** element):

1) First solution: without a function *outside* of addEventListener:

```
var audioApp = document.getElementById('audioApp');
var buttons = audioApp.getElementsByTagName('button');
var players = audioApp.getElementsByTagName('audio');

for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
        console.log(this); // check what this is
        this.children[0].play();
    }, false);
}
```

The **function** *outside* of addEventListener, **usage**:

```
el.addEventListener('click', function() { f(argument) }, false);
```

2) Second solution: with a **function** *outside* of addEventListener:

```
for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
        play(this);
    }, false);
}

function play(current) {
    return current.children[0].play();
}
```

Important is to give over ***this*** as an **argument** of the function.

HTML:

```
<article class='rock' id='audioApp'>
    <section class="containerAudioApp rock">
        <button>Normal
            <audio src="audio/one.mp3"></audio>
        </button>
        <button>Master
            <audio src="audio/two.mp3"></audio>
        </button>
    </section>
    <section class="containerAudioApp rock">
        <button>Normal
            <audio src="audio/one.mp3"></audio>
        </button>
        <button>Master
            <audio src="audio/two.mp3"></audio>
        </button>
    </section>
</article>
```

Comment: Really f*cking genius. Thanks mate.

Comment: You are welcome! Maybe you can specify, clean and clear your question a little bit! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to ask for the index is:

```
Array.prototype.indexOf.call( buttons, this );
```

The reason for that is because *buttons* is a "live HTMLCollection" rather than a normal array, as said in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName). You need to use Array constructor to thread the NodeList as a normal array to use indexOf.

In other words, your play function becomes like this:

```
function play(){
    players.item( Array.prototype.indexOf.call( buttons, this ) ).play();
}
```